# Move object on the vector between mouse and object (canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a game similar to agar.io. I have made a split function to split blobs. But there's a problem in their movement. I want them to move on the vector between (mouseX, mouseY) and (blobX, blobY) with some greater speed. I don't want it to move to (mouseX, mouseY).

Below is my code and a diagram.

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Play Agario Clone</title>

 <style>
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game">
  kindly update your browser.
 </canvas>

 <script>
 var 
 canvas, 
 ctx, 
 width = innerWidth, 
 height = innerHeight,
 mouseX = 0,
 mouseY = 0;

 var

 camera = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,

  // camera
  update: function(obj) {
   this.x = (obj.blobsExtent.minx + obj.blobsExtent.maxx) / 2;
      this.y = (obj.blobsExtent.miny + obj.blobsExtent.maxy) / 2;
      this.x -= width / 2;
      this.y -= height / 2;
  }
 },

 player = {
  defaultMass: 54,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  blobs: [],

  blobsExtent : {
      minx :0,
      miny : 0,
      maxx : 0,
      maxy : 0,
    },

  update: function () {
   var be = this.blobsExtent;
   for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i ++) {
    var x = mouseX + camera.x - this.blobs[i].x;
    var y = mouseY + camera.y - this.blobs[i].y;
    var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
    var speed = 54/this.blobs[i].mass;
    
    this.blobs[i].velX = x/length * speed;
    this.blobs[i].velY = y/length * speed;

    this.blobs[i].x += this.blobs[i].velX;
    this.blobs[i].y += this.blobs[i].velY;

    // prblem here
    if (this.blobs[i].splitted) {
     this.blobs[i].x += x/length * this.blobs[i].speed;
     this.blobs[i].y += x/length * this.blobs[i].speed;

     if (this.blobs[i].speed > 0) {
      this.blobs[i].speed--;
     }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < this.blobs.length; j ++) {
     if (j != i && this.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
            var blob1 = this.blobs[i];
            var blob2 = this.blobs[j];
            var x = blob2.x - blob1.x;
            var y = blob2.y - blob1.y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

            if (dist < blob1.mass + blob2.mass) {
              x /= dist;
              y /= dist;
              blob1.x = blob2.x - x * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
              blob1.y = blob2.y - y * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
            }
          }
    }

    if (i === 0) {
          be.maxx = be.minx = blob1.x;
          be.maxy = be.miny = blob1.y;
        } else {
          be.maxx = Math.max(be.maxx, blob1.x);
          be.maxy = Math.max(be.maxy, blob1.y);
          be.minx = Math.min(be.minx, blob1.x);
          be.miny = Math.min(be.miny, blob1.y);
        }
   }

   this.x += (mouseX - width/2)/(width/2) * 1;
   this.y += (mouseY - height/2)/(height/2) * 1
  },

  split: function (cell) {
   if(cell.mass >= this.defaultMass) {
    cell.mass /= 2;

    this.blobs.push({
     x: cell.x,
     y: cell.y,
     mass: cell.mass,
     splitted: true,
     speed: 20
    });
   }
  },

  draw: function () {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i ++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(-camera.x + this.blobs[i].x, -camera.y + this.blobs[i].y, this.blobs[i].mass, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
   }
  }
 };

 function handleMouseMove (e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
 }

 function handleKeydown (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      var currentLength = player.blobs.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
        player.split(player.blobs[i]);
      }
    }
 }

 function setup () {
  canvas = document.getElementById("game");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
  addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);

  player.blobs.push({
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   mass: player.defaultMass
  });
  player.blobs.push({
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   mass: player.defaultMass/2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
   x: 100,
   y: 100,
   mass: player.defaultMass*2
  });

  var loop = function () {
   update();
   draw();
   requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }

 function update () {
  camera.update(player);
  player.update();
 }

 function draw () {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  player.draw();
 }

 setup();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw this the other time and thought it odd but thought you wanted that way.

```
this.blobs[i].y += x/length * this.blobs[i].speed;
//.................^    should not be x?
```

To move along the vector use y

```
this.blobs[i].y += y/length * this.blobs[i].speed;
//.................^ correction now moves along vector
```

Comment: but it is still not working as I expected. Speed problem is there

Comment: @AbhinavS.Chauhan Not sure what you want to happen. the code suggests you want the split circles to travel faster for 20 frames first 20pixels, then 19pixels down to normal speed. Which they do. Dont forget your view is following the circles, as they approach the mouse the mouse moves away from them and you have no background objects to give you any sense of speed.

Comment: i need your help again
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980016/improve-my-split-mechanism-so-that-its-like-agar-io