# Improve my split mechanism so that it's like agar.io

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been making a clone of agar.io from few days. I have completed up to split function. But my split mechanism is old and boring. I want it to be like agar.io's (accelerate with greater speed and slow down). Open agar.io and play it one time and you will know what I am expecting to improve.

Below is a my code.

```js
var canvas,
  ctx,
  width = innerWidth,
  height = innerHeight,
  mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var camera = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    // camera
    update: function(obj) {
      this.x = (obj.blobsExtent.minx + obj.blobsExtent.maxx) / 2;
      this.y = (obj.blobsExtent.miny + obj.blobsExtent.maxy) / 2;
      this.x -= width / 2;
      this.y -= height / 2;
    }
  },

  player = {
    defaultMass: 54,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    blobs: [],

    blobsExtent: {
      minx: 0,
      miny: 0,
      maxx: 0,
      maxy: 0,
    },

    update: function() {
      var be = this.blobsExtent;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
        var x = mouseX + camera.x - this.blobs[i].x;
        var y = mouseY + camera.y - this.blobs[i].y;
        var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
        var speed = 54 / this.blobs[i].mass;

        this.blobs[i].velX = x / length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));
        this.blobs[i].velY = y / length * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(y / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));

        this.blobs[i].x += this.blobs[i].velX;
        this.blobs[i].y += this.blobs[i].velY;

        for (var j = 0; j < this.blobs.length; j++) {
          if (j != i && this.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
            var blob1 = this.blobs[i];
            var blob2 = this.blobs[j];
            var x = blob2.x - blob1.x;
            var y = blob2.y - blob1.y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

            if (dist < blob1.mass + blob2.mass) {
              x /= dist;
              y /= dist;
              blob1.x = blob2.x - x * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
              blob1.y = blob2.y - y * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
            }
          }
        }

        if (i === 0) {
          be.maxx = be.minx = blob1.x;
          be.maxy = be.miny = blob1.y;
        } else {
          be.maxx = Math.max(be.maxx, blob1.x);
          be.maxy = Math.max(be.maxy, blob1.y);
          be.minx = Math.min(be.minx, blob1.x);
          be.miny = Math.min(be.miny, blob1.y);
        }
      }

      this.x += (mouseX - width / 2) / (width / 2) * 1;
      this.y += (mouseY - height / 2) / (height / 2) * 1
    },

    split: function(cell) {
      if (cell.mass >= this.defaultMass) {
        cell.mass /= 2;

        this.blobs.push({
          x: cell.x,
          y: cell.y,
          mass: cell.mass
        });
      }
    },

    draw: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(-camera.x + this.blobs[i].x, -camera.y + this.blobs[i].y, this.blobs[i].mass, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  };

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
}

function handleKeydown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    var currentLength = player.blobs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
      player.split(player.blobs[i]);
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("game");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
  addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);

  player.blobs.push({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    mass: player.defaultMass
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    mass: player.defaultMass / 2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    mass: player.defaultMass / 2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    mass: player.defaultMass / 2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    mass: player.defaultMass * 2
  });

  var loop = function() {
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function update() {
  camera.update(player);
  player.update();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(-camera.x + 0, -camera.y + 0, 20, 20);

  player.draw();
}

setup();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<title>Play Agario Clone</title>
<canvas id="game">Kindly update your browser.</canvas>
```

space bar to split.

I want the splitted blob to first go at a higher speed and then slow down. All blob updates are done from player.update

Comment: (I won't, but don't ask people not to downvote)

Comment: I would suggest you try to be more specific about what your problem is. Highlight the exact code that needs improving, and explain how you want to improve it. Do not just link another library and expect us to guess what you want

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a mess as I don't have that much time. Added a quick background grid to show movement.

Added the speed property back to the blobs and use it to control the speed of all blobs, not just the split ones. When a blob splits I give the two split blobs a new speed (8 but up to you)

Just after calculating the velocity of each blob if the speed > 1 (in the case of split blobs) I reduce the speed by multiplying by a number very close to 1 (0.995) this reduces the speed slowly over many frames. The closer you make this number to 1 the longer the speed up lasts. The number must be below 1 or the blobs will keep on get faster and faster.

```js
// need something to see relative movement so this is to add a background grid
var gPattern;

function createGridPattern() {
  const grid = document.createElement("canvas");
  grid.width = 128;
  grid.height = 128;
  grid.ctx = grid.getContext("2d");
  grid.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  grid.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  const alphas = [1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2];
  grid.ctx.fillStyle = "black";

  for (var x = 0; x < 128; x += 16) {
    grid.ctx.globalAlpha = alphas[(x / 16) % 4];
    grid.ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 1, 128);
    grid.ctx.fillRect(0, x, 128, 1);
  }

  return ctx.createPattern(grid,"repeat");
}





var
  canvas,
  ctx,
  width = innerWidth,
  height = innerHeight,
  mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var

  camera = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    // camera
    update: function(obj) {
      this.x = (obj.blobsExtent.minx + obj.blobsExtent.maxx) / 2;
      this.y = (obj.blobsExtent.miny + obj.blobsExtent.maxy) / 2;
      this.x -= width / 2;
      this.y -= height / 2;
    }
  },

  player = {
    defaultMass: 54,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    blobs: [],

    blobsExtent: {
      minx: 0,
      miny: 0,
      maxx: 0,
      maxy: 0,
    },

    update: function() {
      var be = this.blobsExtent;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
        var x = mouseX + camera.x - this.blobs[i].x;
        var y = mouseY + camera.y - this.blobs[i].y;
        var length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
        var speed = 54 / this.blobs[i].mass;
        this.blobs[i].velX = x / length * this.blobs[i].speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));
        this.blobs[i].velY = y / length * this.blobs[i].speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(y / this.blobs[i].mass, 2));
        if(this.blobs[i].speed > 1){
            this.blobs[i].speed *= 0.995; // make speed a little slow each frame
                       // make the 0.995 closer to 1 to make the speedup last longer
                       // eg 0.999 will keep speed longer
                       // this number must be less than 1
        }else{
            this.blobs[i].speed = 1;
        }
        this.blobs[i].x += this.blobs[i].velX;
        this.blobs[i].y += this.blobs[i].velY;
        for (var j = 0; j < this.blobs.length; j++) {
          if (j != i && this.blobs[i] !== undefined) {
            var blob1 = this.blobs[i];
            var blob2 = this.blobs[j];
            var x = blob2.x - blob1.x;
            var y = blob2.y - blob1.y;
            var dist = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

            if (dist < blob1.mass + blob2.mass) {
              x /= dist;
              y /= dist;
              blob1.x = blob2.x - x * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
              blob1.y = blob2.y - y * (blob1.mass + blob2.mass);
            }
          }
        }

        if (i === 0) {
          be.maxx = be.minx = blob1.x;
          be.maxy = be.miny = blob1.y;
        } else {
          be.maxx = Math.max(be.maxx, blob1.x);
          be.maxy = Math.max(be.maxy, blob1.y);
          be.minx = Math.min(be.minx, blob1.x);
          be.miny = Math.min(be.miny, blob1.y);
        }
      }

      this.x += (mouseX - width / 2) / (width / 2) * 1;
      this.y += (mouseY - height / 2) / (height / 2) * 1
    },

    split: function(cell) {
      if (cell.mass >= this.defaultMass) {
        cell.mass /= 2;
        cell.speed = 8;  // this is the amount of extra speed when split

        this.blobs.push({
          x: cell.x,
          y: cell.y,
          mass: cell.mass,
          speed : 8,  // this is the amount of extra speed when split
        });
      }
    },

    draw: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.blobs.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(-camera.x + this.blobs[i].x, -camera.y + this.blobs[i].y, this.blobs[i].mass, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  };

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
}

function handleKeydown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    var currentLength = player.blobs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < currentLength; i++) {
      player.split(player.blobs[i]);
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("game");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
  addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);

  player.blobs.push({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    speed : 1,
    mass: player.defaultMass
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    speed : 1,
    
    mass: player.defaultMass / 2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    speed : 1,
    mass: player.defaultMass / 2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    speed : 1,
    mass: player.defaultMass / 2
  });
  player.blobs.push({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    speed : 1,
    mass: player.defaultMass * 2
  });

  var loop = function() {
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  }
  
  gPattern = createGridPattern();
  loop();

}

function update() {
  camera.update(player);
  player.update();
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillStyle = gPattern;

  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,(-camera.x % 128) - 128, (-camera.y % 128) - 128);
  ctx.fillRect(0,0, width+256, height+256);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(-camera.x + 0, -camera.y + 0, 20, 20);

  player.draw();
}

setup();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding : 0px;
  margin : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game">
 </canvas>
```

Comment: I want some lerp effect too and the blob should go through the existing blobs when splitted